# localization View not Return value from resource file

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

for 2 days I hit my head on this thing without getting to grips with it.

With .NET Core 3.1 on a clean project done perfectly, within a project the same resource files and the same classes do not return the value of the resource (no runtime or compilation errors). I also tried to remove all references from ConfigureServices other than the clean project but nothing ..

Thanks to those who can give me some advice!

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Dependency Injection per leggere Localizzazione File Resources delle lingue            
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("de"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr"),
                    new CultureInfo("es"),
                    new CultureInfo("ru"),
                    new CultureInfo("ja"),
                    new CultureInfo("ar"),
                    new CultureInfo("zh"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-GB")
                };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });

            services.AddSingleton<CommonLocalizationService>();

            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                {
                    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(CommonResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                    return factory.Create(nameof(CommonResources), assemblyName.Name);
                };
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();


            services.AddMvc(options => {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            });

            // Aggiungi Supporto Sessioni
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            // File di Configurazione JSON            
            //services.AddOptions(); // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>

            // File di Configurazione JSON - Add our Config object so it can be injected
            services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            services.Configure<Smtp>(Configuration.GetSection("Smtp"));
            services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));


            services.AddSingleton<IMyConfigurationECommerce, MyConfigurationECommerce>();            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession(); // Aggiungi Supporto Sessioni

            // Dependency Injection Option per leggere Localizzazione File Resources delle lingue
            var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

```
    public class CommonLocalizationService
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;
        public CommonLocalizationService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(CommonResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            localizer = factory.Create(nameof(CommonResources), assemblyName.Name);
        }

        public string Get(string key)
        {
            return localizer[key];
        }
    }
```

```
@inject CommonLocalizationService localizer
@model WebApplication6.Models.ContactModel

<h1>@localizer.Get("Contact")</h1>
```

In the Project Root I have:

```
/Resources/CommonResources.cs
/Resources/CommonResources.de.resx
/Resources/CommonResources.en.resx
```

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. Could you please tell me how you tested the culture? By using querystring or httpheader or else?

Comment: I solved the problem (not understanding the motivation well) but still placed the solution for the forum:

Basically I saw that the namespace obtained from the following instructions returned an incorrect namespace with an ".resources" too

Changing the namespace name to "nomenamespace.Resources" of the generic class of the resource file worked correctly!